# Multiple var inside onclick: Strings and Int

Tags: javascript

Currently I have this code

```
function myFunction(arr)
{
 var out = "<br />";
 var i;

 if(arr.length > 0)
 {
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
   out += "<div class='address container-fluid card svs-map-add' title='Show Location and Coordinates' onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat + ", " + arr[i].lon + ");return false;'>" + arr[i].display_name + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = out;
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Sorry, no results...";
 }

}
```

As you can see here I'm passing 2 variables and it contains `latitude` and `longitude`

`onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat + ", " + arr[i].lon + ");return false;'`

These variables will go to function `chooseAddr`

Currently it's working fine

But now I need to include `1 more` variable and it's

`arr[i].display_name`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

What I have done right now is

```
  onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat + ", " + arr[i].lon + ", \'" + arr[i].display_name + "\');return false;'
```

But there's an error with that syntax

How can I pass the `display_name` variable since this variable is `String`

Comment: you will have add the variable you want in the array composition

Comment: `onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat`, you are missing a single quote after the double quote, and the same to the rest of the concatenation. You used single quote to start the string, then every time you concatenate something, it must end also with a single quote. Plus you didn't tell us the error

Comment: See the updated question

Comment: you can send it as second argument in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out += "<div class='address container-fluid card svs-map-add' title='Show Location and Coordinates' onclick='chooseAddr(" + arr[i].lat + ", " + arr[i].lon + ",\""+arr[i].display_name+"\");return false;'>"+arr[i].display_name+"</div>"
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at some of the questions on SO re inline JS one of the most common problems is how quotes/escaping quotes is meant to work when you add variables into the mix. Rather than explain where the problem is here's a more modern solution to your problem.

The idea is that you separate out your JS from your HTML and use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to contain the element-specific data. Further, you add an event listener to a parent element to [catch clicks](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and call your `chooseAddr` function to process the data of the clicked element.

```js
const arr = [{ lat: 1, lng: 1, display_name: "Rita" }, { lat: 2, lng: 2, display_name: "Sue" }, { lat: 3, lng: 3, display_name: "Bob" }];

// We create some HTML by using `map` to iterate over the array
// and return a string (we're using a template literal here for convenience)
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
// We add the lat/lng data as data attributes on the div.
const html = arr.map((el) => {
  return `
    <div data-lat="${el.lat}" data-lng="${el.lng}" class="address container-fluid card svs-map-add" title="Show Location and Coordinates">
      ${el.display_name}
    </div>
  `;

// `map` returns an array so don't forget to `join` it up into a string
}).join('');

// We've created a parent element called "wrapper", so we need
// a) to pick it up
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

// b) add the HTML inside it
wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

// c) add a listener to it to listen for clicks (that bubble
// up the DOM) and call `chooseAddr`
wrapper.addEventListener('click', chooseAddr, false);

function chooseAddr(e) {

  // Destructure the lat/lng data from the dataset of
  // the target (the element that was clicked)
  const { target: { dataset: { lat, lng } } } = e;
  console.log(lat, lng);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" />
```

I appreciate this is a lot to take in but if you use a separation of concerns with your code you'll find it a lot easier to manage. I hope this helps.

#### Further reading

- Data attributes [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [Dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a seprate parameter

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick='chooseAddr( param1 + ", " + param2,  "param3" );return false;'/>

// or pass in array
<input type="button" value="test" onclick='chooseAddr1( "param1" + ", " + "param2" + ", test" );return false;'/>
```

**Now you need to handle it in your script**

```
 function chooseAddr(arr,data) {
// do your code
}
function chooseAddr1(arr) {
// do your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add strings in better way using backticks and ${};

Example:

```
var myString = `Some text ${someVariable}`
```

Here is codepen with you sample: 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/gmaslic/pen/eYYpQQL?editors=0111)